# PostgreSQL directory on SSD

Tags: pi-3b+, database

I have a Raspberry Pi 3 on my network with PostgreSQL installed on it.

At first, I had some tables installed on it, and saved on SD, and it worked perfectly. I had enabled entrance from the network and I had access from any pgAdmin client.

Lately, I have decided to connect an SSD to the system in order to have more safety for my data, more space, and more portability.

So, I connect the SSD, copy there the folder with PostgreSQL data, check to have all rights for all users, and I changed the directory in Postgres files.

The problem now. After a lot of searching, I found that the cluster is disabled, and this is because the user of the new databases folder in SSD is not the same as the PostgreSQL installation.

I tried to change the owner of files in SSD but even I do not receive any fail, it simply does not work and the owner remains the same.

Any help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using ext4 filesystem on the SSD ... or something like NTFS or even FAT32?